# Can i deploy my website from remote Mercurial Repo, which is protected by a password?

Tags: azure, mercurial

I'm trying to deploy my website on some asp.net hosting, and so far Azure seems to be satisfying all my wishes.

I use Hg repository, which is accessible via https and requires login-password authentication. Azure doesn't allow me to input it manually and so i get this error:

```
abort: http authorization required
```

Is there any way i can set my credentials to Azure so i can complete the deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Check out the `[auth]` section in the [`hgrc` man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) to see how to specify http authorization information in your repoistory's `.hg/hgrc` file.